# HG Test Merge then Commit

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch, commit

I would like to merge a feature branch with another, and test the code.

Can I do a merge, run code on the branch, then if I am satisfied, `Commit` ?

Will this have any negative effects ?

Comment: Why haven't you tried before asking? "Will this have any negative effects" --- uhm, like what?

Comment: I have, it seems to work - I was wondering whether i am breaking something though

Comment: isn't it expected workflow? You merge, you check, you commit. I haven't seen the requirement to commit immediately after merge ever, have you?

Comment: OK, thank you. It is what I thought and what I was hoping, just wasn't sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not have any negative side effects - in fact, that's what you're supposed to do.